# How messenger application saves thumbnails

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, thumbnails, telegram

I'm developing android application. I searched about thumbnails and the way that other messenger application use them. but I don't know how Telegram or WhatsApp  save their thumbnail and where are their thumbnail on my android device. Any suggestion?